# Determine load address and entry point of stripped Linux Kernel image

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, entry-point, symbol-tables, nm

I have a crosscompiling toolchain for an embedded system (mipsel) on my x86 Linux. I know how to build a custom kernel (let's call the image "vmlinux") for it and how to strip that image via

```
objcopy -S -O binary vmlinux vmlinux.bin
```

For further processing I also need the load address and entry point of the image. **Before** stripping it is no problem to determine them via `scripts/mksysmap` or, more explicitly, via

```
nm -n vmlinux | grep -v '\( [aNUw] \)\|\(__crc_\)\|\( \$[adt]\)' > System.map
```

Then I can determine the load address and entry point via

```
awk '/A _text/ { print "0x"$1; }' < _System.map
awk '/T kernel_entry/ { print "0x"$1; }' < System.map
```

Now the challenge is that sometimes I do not build the kernel by myself, but get a pre-built kernel **after** it has already been stripped of its symbols via *objcopy*. Can anybody tell me how to do this? I am not very proficient in kernel building and toolchain usage. Both *nm* and *objdump* do not like the stripped image, saying

```
vmlinux.bin: File format not recognized
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [objcopy manual page](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/binutils-2.9.1/man/objcopy.1.html)

objcopy can be used to generate a raw binary file by using an output target of binary (e.g., use **-O binary**). When objcopy generates a raw binary file, it will essentially produce a memory dump of the contents of the input object file. All symbols and relocation information will be discarded. The memory dump will start at the virtual address of the lowest section copied into the output file.

Here is an example that could be used on the PowerPC architecture:

**original vmlinux**

```
bash-3.2$ file vmlinux
vmlinux: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

**stripped vmlinux is considered a "data" file**

```
bash-3.2$ file vmlinux.bin
vmlinux.bin: data
```

**convert binary to ELF format for the PowerPC**

```
bash-3.2$ powerpc-440fp-linux-objcopy -I binary vmlinux.bin -B powerpc -O elf32-powerpc vmlinux.bin.x
```

**output of vmlinux is now considered an ELF file**

```
bash-3.2$ file vmlinux.bin.x
vmlinux.bin.x: ELF 32-bit MSB relocatable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

You must pass the **-I**, **-B** and **-O** parameter. You can get this parameters from your objcopy documentation.

But since your binary is stripped already trying to decompile it might not be worthwhile since the section information is not available. All of the data in the file will be dumped into the .data secion.

Comment: Belated thanks for that answer. Unfortunately I did not get notified about the answer via e-mail, sorry. Actually I managed to find another way to find out the load address and entry point, but my solution was specific to the situation and cannot be applied generally, so I am not quoting it here.

Let me just say that your proposed solution does create an ELF file, but the file does not contain the desired relocation information. Thus, the information cannot be extracted from it via `nm -n`.

Thanks for answering anyway.